# How do I defeat Volcanicrab, the Ignan Ruins boss?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

I'm almost done Ignan Ruins, the second dungeon of Chantelise...except for what clearly seems to be the most difficult part, the boss.

Volcanicrab seems impossible to damage with my sword, front and back, and doesn't seem to offer me any magic shards even when I swing at it. Magic manages to chip away its health, but without any way to get more shards to cast more spells, I can't seem to figure out how I'm supposed to inflict much damage at all.

Is there something I'm missing here? How do I defeat Volcanicrab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two general ways you can defeat this boss.

The first is the obviously hard way, and that's straight up force. Gather enough blue gems from the previous rooms, equip yourself with any staves to boost your attack power, and open up with all of your damage. Then, switch to the Water Crystal (I hope you bought it) and equip any gloves you have. The more, the better! In essence, you want to dodge all of his attacks and hang out in front, then sneak in a charge attack. It may take a while, but you can certainly take him down this way.

The smarter way.

> If you perform a combo attack on the boss in his face (3 hit combo, so probably shouldn't use the Wind Crystal), then it will knock him backwards. Take care to avoid his claw swipes while sneaking in another combo, and knock him into those giant fire pits. This will cause him to be blasted out, and land on his back, where you will deal significantly more damage, he cannot attack you, *and* he will yield more gemstones.

It won't take too many rounds of this to succeed, and you'll win!

Comment: I see. Turned out that I could damage him from the front, although I had to really get right up in his face(past the claws) to do so.